# Vertex AI - No module named 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.remote on ModelDeployOp(...)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops

I have created a simple pipeline that trains a model and deploys it to a Vertex AI endpoint. I have noticed that while attempting to deploy the model using the  `google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.ModelDeployOp()` component, it returns an error.

If we look at the documentation of [google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.1.5/google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.html), we can find two entries for ModelDeployOp(). One illustrates how they [converted the original Methods into components](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.1.5/google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.html#google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.utils.convert_method_to_component), the other is the documentation on [how to use the ModelDeployOp()](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.1.5/google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.html#google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.ModelDeployOp)method.

If we look at how they convert the Method, we find the following information:
...

```
Generates and invokes the following Component:
name: Model-deploy inputs: - {name: project, type: String} - {name: endpoint, type: Artifact} - {name: model, type: Model} outputs: - {name: endpoint, type: Artifact} implementation:

container:
image: gcr.io/sashaproject-1/mb_sdk_component:latest command: - python3 - remote_runner.py - –cls_name=Model - –method_name=deploy - –method.deployed_model_display_name=my-deployed-model - –method.machine_type=n1-standard-4 args: - –resource_name_output_artifact_path - {outputPath: endpoint} - –init.project - {inputValue: project} - –method.endpoint - {inputPath: endpoint} - –init.model_name - {inputPath: model}
```

While looking at my error that gcp logging retruned:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.remote.aiplatform.remote_runner' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.remote')
```

It seems that its an issue from inside the container itself.

So... I suppose my question is if I am correct in assuming this is a bug in the library? Are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem (same error message, different container) with Kubeflow pipelines. This is the danger of using :latest tag. What worked a few days ago does not work today. In my case I solved this by changing gcr.io/ml-pipeline/google-cloud-pipeline-components:latest to the previous version gcr.io/ml-pipeline/google-cloud-pipeline-components:0.1.7 (latest tag was a recently deployed 0.1.8 with what looks like a missing library dependency) giving the same can't find remote module error.

Comment: The google_cloud_pipeline_components get you the version of the container corresponding to (actually, defined by) the version of the package that you installed. So this is not a question of running on a container with the "latest" tag. If it started failing, I think this is because the OP changed the version of google_cloud_pipeline_components and I'm not sure, but yes, it might be a bug.